# Leaflet : icon based on data source

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I am building a website with Leaflet map that uses a data source to populate the map and the popups. Here is how my JSON data looks like:

```
{
  "time_exo": null,
  "time_stm": 1541787833,
  "results": [
    {
      "agency": "STM",
      "icon": "busSTMIcon",
      "vehicle_id": "22210",
      "route_id": "55",
      "trip_id": "188767688",
      "start_time": "12:59:00",
      "start_date": "20181109",
      "current_stop_sequence": 20,
      "current_status": 2,
      "lat": 45.52397,
      "lon": -73.59475
    },
    ...
}
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
 $.get(dataUrl, function(data, pos_status) {
    console.log("pos call result: " + pos_status);
    // show data on map
    data.results.forEach(function(element) {
      L.marker(L.latLng(element.lat, element.lon), {
          icon: busSTMIcon
        }).addTo(posLayer)
        .bindPopup("<h3>" + element.agency + " " + element.vehicle_id + "</h3><b>Trip: </b> " + element.trip_id + "<br><b>Route: </b>" + element.route_id + "<br><b>Start: </b>" + element.start_date + element.start_time + "<br><b>Current stop sequence: </b>" + element.current_stop_sequence + "<br><b>Status: </b>" + element.current_status);
    });
 });
```

Here is how I declare my busSTMIcon :

```
var busSTMIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://felixinx.github.io/mtl-gtfs-rt/assets/map-bus-stm.svg',
  iconSize: [20, 20]
});
```

Currently I use the static way which causes all markers to have the same icon. I would like to have the icon based on my data source. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the icon variable as part of an object (to which you could add other icons):

```
var icons = { 
  "busSTMIcon" : L.icon({ iconUrl: 'https://felixinx.github.io/mtl-gtfs-rt/assets/map-bus-stm.svg', iconSize: [20, 20] }) 
};
```

and then you would write

```
icon: icons[element.icon]
```

(instead of `icon: busSTMIcon`)

then it would dynamically pick the right item from the icons object based on the string in `element.icon`

Comment: That's what I try but it dosen't work. The way that Leaflet work, you have to first declare the icon : ```var busSTMIcon = L.icon({ iconUrl: 'https://felixinx.github.io/mtl-gtfs-rt/assets/map-bus-stm.svg', iconSize: [20, 20] });```

Comment: what is the content of your `busSTMIcon` variable in your original code?

Comment: Ok then, so I think then you need it so that `element.icon` contains `{
  "iconUrl": "https://felixinx.github.io/mtl-gtfs-rt/assets/map-bus-stm.svg",
  "iconSize": [20, 20]
}` . Are you able to change your code to output that in the JSON? And then you'd write `icon: L.icon(element.icon)`

Comment: Either that or create the icon as part of an object (to which you could add other icons): `var icons = { "busSTMIcon" : L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://felixinx.github.io/mtl-gtfs-rt/assets/map-bus-stm.svg',
  iconSize: [20, 20]
}) };` and then you would write `icon: icons[element.icon]` so it would dynamically pick the right item from the icons object based on the string in `element.icon`.

Comment: You last solution did work. I didn't think of doing it that way. Could you update your answer to your last comment? Thanks!